# Trac, how to organize pages hierarchically?

Tags: wiki, bug-tracking, trac, bug-tracker

I use [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) to manage my projects and I'd like to organize wiki pages the same way trac project does, i.e. by category, subcategory, etc. [TitleIndex](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TitleIndex) page on trac site gives a good explanation of the result I want to obtain.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: For further reference there is an answer on SO titled [How to define parent and subpages in Trac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287806/how-to-define-parent-and-subpages-in-trac) that also helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can create hierarchically wiki pages, just by modifying the url, and press enter. It is also possible to create a wikilink first, and then press the red link.

For example, when your trac home page is `http://trac.server.local/project/wiki`, you can type `/customers` at the end of the url, and press enter. So the new url would be `http://trac.server.local/project/wiki/customers`. You will get an almost empty page with a button `Create this page`. Press that button to create that page. After that you can also create pages at the next level, for example

- `http://trac.server.local/project/wiki/customers/microsoft`
- `http://trac.server.local/project/wiki/customers/google`
- `http://trac.server.local/project/wiki/customers/apple`

To generate an index, I use the [HierWikiPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/HierWikiPlugin). On the `/wiki/customers` page, I enter just

```
[[SubWiki(customers/,1)]]
```

to get a list of all subpages below customers. To also see the subpages of those subpages, increase the level, for example

```
[[SubWiki(customers/,2)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add subpages using something like:

```
[[./SubPage]]
```

This generates a link to a non-existent page. When you click on the link, Trac shows you a page to create a new sub page or a page in the same level...